# Connecting to user instance of systemd on Tizen

Tags: tizen, systemd

So, I've read the porting guide (https://wiki.tizen.org/wiki/Porting_Guide). There is a section named "Tizen Bootup Overview". This section says that user instance of systemd daemon is run. When I run the emulator I can see it with `ps aux | grep systemd` and I see that it is run by user `app`. But when I type in `systemctl --user list-units` as `app` user I recieve following message `Failed to issue method call: Failed to execute program /bin/false: Success`. But when I type in `/usr/lib/systemd/systemd --user &` as `app` user and only the call to list-units method it runs ok. What I don't understand properly about running `systemctl --user list-units`, please?

As far as I understand the DBus service file already has /bin/false as the executable specified, to avoid `systemd --user` from being accidentally DBus-activated.
But looking at the sources of `systemctl` I see that when running with `--user` option it tries to connect to DBus to `"unix:path=$XDG_RUNTIME_PATH/systemd/private"`

I'm pretty new to both systemd and dbus. I tried calling `/usr/lib/systemd/systemd --user &` from my program before it connected to systemd and it worked, but systemd began the executing user targets.
I connect to DBus with `dbus_bus_get(DBUS_BUS_SESSION, &err)` (`DBUS_BUS_SESSION` is to connect to user instance, as I understand by looking atthe sources of `systemd & Co`)

PS: Tizen uses `systemd v43`

Thanks in advance.

Sorry for my broken English.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is:
To connect to the user session of systemd:

`$ su -`

`# su - app`

`app$ export XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/app`

`app$ systemctl --user status default.target`